# Browserify angularjs failed to load module

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, browserify

Every time I run my gulp file to browserify and coffeeify my files with :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.coffee', { read: false })
        .pipe(browserify({ transform: ['coffeeify'], extensions: ['.coffee'] }))
        .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dest/'));
});

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.run('scripts');
});
```

I have a weird error on my first line of bundle.js that I dont understand :

[image: Weird bug with browserify]

Can you help me with this ? I dont understand nothing at all with this error :-/

---

This is my app.coffee code (permitting to start the application)

```
require('angular')
require('angular-route')

Application = require('./Application')
application = new Application()
application.start()
```

This is my application.coffee class

```
Route = require('./Route')
Configuration = require('../../config/config')
Routes = require('../../config/route')

class Application

    constructor: ()->
        @name = Configuration.appName
        @dependencies = Configuration.dependencies

    start: ()->
        angular.module @name, @dependencies
        angular.config(@config)

    getName: () ->
        return @name

    getDependencies: ()->
        return @dependencies

    config: ($routeProvider)->
        for r in Routes
            split = r.controller.split(":")
            module = split[0]
            controller = split[1] + 'Controller'
            method = split[2] + 'Action'
            vue = module + '/partials/' + r.view

            @initController(module, controller, method, r.dependencies)
            @handleRouting($routeProvider, vue, controller + '.' + method)

    initController: (module, ctrl, method, dependencies)->
        controller = new (require('../../modules/' + module + '/controller/' + ctrl))
        angular.module(@name, dependencies).controller(eval(controller + '.' + method + '()'))

    handleRouting: (routeProvider, vue, controller) ->
        route = new Route(vue, controller)
        if r.alias
            route.setAlias(r.alias)
        if r.resolve
            route.setResolve(r.resolve)
        routeProvider.when(r.pattern, @handleRouting(vue, controller).getRoute())


module.exports = Application
```

And this is my route class

```
class Route

    constructor: (@template, @controller)->

    getTemplate: ()->
        return @template
    setTemplate: (@template)->

    getController: ()->
        return @controller
    setController: (@controller)->

    getAlias: ()->
        return @alias
    setAlias: (@alias)->

    getResolve: ()->
        return @resolve
    setResolve: (@resole)->

    getRoute: ()->
        route = {}
        route.templateUrl = @template
        route.controller = @controller

        if @alias
            route.controllerAs = @alias
        if @resolve
            route.resolve = @resolve
        return

module.exports = Route
```

Thanks for advance

EDITED : the full error in text ->

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);throw new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'")}var f=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(f.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},f,f.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s}'
```

Comment: error is not readable, you might want to post a text version of it.